Role Protection in ReactJS tsx
I am trying to implement role-based protection in ReactJS (typescript) application.
I have searched the web for this topic, there are many tutorials and confusions between typescript version, V6 react-router-dom (I am using V6) and so on.
I have build the basic functionality and this code is working:
Here is my App.tsx
import { useRef } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AboutPrograms from './components/landing/AboutPrograms/AboutPrograms';
import SignIn from './components/landing/SignIn/SignIn';
import Header from './components/landing/Header/Header';
// ...
import { AuthProvider } from './components/personal_account/AuthContext/AuthContext';
import PrivateWrapper from './components/personal_account/PrivateWrapper/PrivateWrapper';
import MainStudentPage from './components/personal_account/StudentPage/MainStudentPage/MainStudentPage';
import MainTeacherPage from './components/personal_account/TeacherPage/MainTeacherPage/MainTeacherPage';

function App() {
  const admissionFormRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <>
                  <Header />
                  <AboutPrograms />
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route path="/log_in" element={<SignIn />} />
            <Route
              path="/student"
              element={
                <PrivateWrapper>
                  <MainStudentPage />
                </PrivateWrapper>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/teacher"
              element={
                <PrivateWrapper>
                  <MainTeacherPage />
                </PrivateWrapper>
              }
            />
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

This is my AuthProvider:
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  ReactNode,
  FC,
} from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// TODO: two more interfaces
interface User {
  name: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
}

interface AuthContextProps {
  user: User | null;
  login: (userData: User) => void;
  logout: () => void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = (userData: User) => {
    setUser(userData);
    localStorage.setItem('role', userData.name);
    if (userData.role === 'student') {
      navigate('/student');
    }
    if (userData.role === 'teacher') {
      navigate('/teacher');
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('role');
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = (): AuthContextProps => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

And this is my SignIn.tsx element
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useAuth } from '../../personal_account/AuthContext/AuthContext';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import './SignIn.css';

const SignIn = () => {
  const [loginFrom, setLoginForm] = useState('');
  const [passwordForm, setPasswordForm] = useState('');

  const { login } = useAuth();

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    login({ name: loginFrom, password: passwordForm, role: loginFrom });
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const role = localStorage.getItem('role');
    if (role === 'student') {
      navigate('/student');
    }
    if (role === 'teacher') {
      navigate('/teacher');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="signin__general">
        <div className="signin__form-container">
          <h2 className="signin__title"> Вход в ЛК &#128526; </h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="signin__form">
            <div className="signin__input-group">
              <label htmlFor="login" className="signin__label">
                Логин
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="login"
                value={loginFrom}
                onChange={(e) => setLoginForm(e.target.value)}
                className="signin__input"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="signin__input-group">
              <label htmlFor="password" className="signin__label">
                Пароль
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                value={passwordForm}
                onChange={(e) => setPasswordForm(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="signin__button">
              Войти
            </button>
            <p className="signin__info">
              Пока вход не доступен, но мы скоро вернёмся !{' '}
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignIn;

And finally PrivateWrapper.tsx:
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useAuth } from '../AuthContext/AuthContext';

const PrivateWrapper = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const storedRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
  if (storedRole) {
    return storedRole ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
  return auth?.user ? children : <Navigate to="/log_in" replace />;
};

export default PrivateWrapper;

As I said it is working okay.
My question is, how do I implement role-based access?
I need the following behaviour - if user is authenticated and it is student - he must have access only to MainStudentPage element.
If user is authenticated and it is teacher - he must have access only to MainTeacherPage element.
I could not find the way to do it without using redux and with V6 react-router-dom.
On which level should I make this check? On the level of App.tsx or somewhere in PrivateWrapper.tsx?
Thank you in advance!
EDIT ONE
Since I am a backend developer who is forced to write production ready code for frontend part I also want to clarify this: I will send a auth request from ReactJS app and will get an access_token with valuable payload.
I have intention to store insensible data in localStorage, but every authenticated request to backend API will be used with this access token. Is it okay to store part of user data in localStorage for quick access ? For instance my decision to store the role in localStorage is okay? Or should I store it in encrypted access token?

You could leverage the AuthProvider (or make a PermissionsProvider the level beneath it) to store role information and update it when appropriate. Then you could create a usePermissions hook and <NeedsPermission/> wrapping component that accepted a role or array of roles as a prop; then you would check the roles the user has against the roles needed to access the content.  That's just one option— you could also just use some singleton service for managing roles or, if all else fails, Redux.  But I think Redux would be overkill here, and you could bake it in similar to how you did Auth.

I am sorry, can you provide some code snippet for the first option..? I am just a backend developer who has to right production-ready code for backend...

You could add a new prop to your PrivateWrapper component, for a required role (pass the role string when you are registering your routes) . And then just do a quick check using the auth object that is already inside it, and the prop with the required role, and just do a redirect if the user isnt allowed.
